# CSVファイルデータのデータ型変換について: astype しても dtype が変わらない

Tags: python, python3, pandas

下記のコードでコラムTOPIX dのデータをString型に変えようとしているのですが、
`data.dtypes`でデータ型を確認すると、オリジナルと変わらずobject型のままで表示されます。

どうしてでしょうか・・・・・

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("forcasting topx.csv", header=0)

#冒頭数行を削除
data = df.drop([0,1,2,3])

#型の変更
data['TOPIX d'].astype(np.str)
data.dtypes
```

Answer (score 1):

文字列に関しては、`numpy`と`pandas`で扱いが異なります。`numpy`は配列の中に文字列を固定長で持つ`np.str`型がありますが、`pandas`の方はDataFrameの中で文字列を持つことはなくオブジェクトへのポインターだけを持っているので`object`型となります。`pandas`で`np.str`型にしたいと思っても変換することはできません。

データをString型に変えようとするのか理由がわかりませんが、もともと文字列になる要素であれば、DataFrameの個々の要素は`str`型になっているので何も心配をする必要はありません。

また、要素の中に数値が含まれていて、それを文字列に変更したいのであれば、`astype(str)`で変換できます。`DataFrame`を`dtypes`で調べると`object`型のままですが、個々の要素の型を調べるときちんと`str`型になっています。

```
data = pd.DataFrame([['a'], ['b'], [3]])
>>> data = pd.DataFrame([['a'], ['b'], [3]])
>>> type(data.iloc[2,0])
<class 'int'>
>>> data[0] = data[0].astype(str)
>>> type(data.iloc[2,0])
<class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`pandas.DataFrame.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) は、キャストした内容を戻り値にするだけであり、元の dataframe の内容を変える関数ではありません。以下はこのことのサンプルコードです。

```
>>> ser = pd.Series([1, 2], dtype='int32')
>>> ser.astype('int64')
0    1
1    2
dtype: int64
>>> ser
0    1
1    2
dtype: int32
```

文字列型の値として扱いたければ、`astype` した結果を代入するか、[`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) のオプション引数 `dtype` を使ってはじめから dtype を指定してあげれば良いです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！ご鞭撻いただいた点はしりませんでした。勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。

ただ、私のコードは
data['TOPIX d'].astype(np.str)
の結果を出力した時点ですでに typesがobjectのままになっており、そもそも変換ができていないようです、、どうしてでしょうか、、、

Comment: こちらでは CSV ファイルがなく状況が再現できないので、質問文に CSV ファイルの中身の小さいサンプルを追記して頂けませんでしょうか？　質問文の下の「編集」から自由に追記ができます。